# Android ListView not showing data from Custom Adapter

Tags: android, xml, listview

Please help, I've looked at hundreds of solutions on here, but it seems like all of the solutions for those problems were already implemented in my code.

Basically, I'm writing an android app that access a MySQL database and returns the results to a listview for the user to click. I have the fetching done, and the data is parse correctly and stored into Request object, and then put into a Request array list. But, when using the custom adapter, nothing seems to display. PLEASE HELP!!

Request Adapter:

```
 public class RequestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Request> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Request> reqs;

    public RequestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Request> requests) {
        super(context, 0, requests);
        this.context=context;
        this.reqs=requests;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Request request = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)         context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.request_list, parent,     false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView req = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ReqID);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        TextView desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Description);
        TextView pickup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.PickupAdd);
        TextView dropoff = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DropOffAdd);
        TextView count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemCount);
        TextView cost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Cost);
        TextView driveracc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DriverAccepted);
        TextView status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Status);
        TextView user = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.User);
        TextView completed = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IsCompleted);


        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        req.setText("Request Number: "+request.getRequestID());
        date.setText("Date: "+request.getDate());
        desc.setText("Description: "+request.getDescription());
        pickup.setText(request.getPickupAddress());
        dropoff.setText(request.getDropOffAddress());
        count.setText(request.getNumItems());
        cost.setText(request.getPrice().toString());
        driveracc.setText(request.getDriverName());
        status.setText(request.getCurrStatus());
        user.setText(request.getUser());
        completed.setText(request.getCompleted().toString());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return reqs.size();
        }
    }
```

Main Class calling the Adapter:

```
`package com.JunkAway;

    public class Active_Requests extends AppCompatActivity {
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private View mProgressView;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> requestsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_requests = "https://people.eecs.ku.edu/~cduddy/JunkAway/PullActiveRequests.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "requests";

private Request request;
private User user;
private TextView nothingfound;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;

ArrayList<Request> arrayOfRequests=new ArrayList<Request>();
//RequestAdapter adapter;
// products JSONArray
//JSONArray requests = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_active__requests);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    user = (User)i.getSerializableExtra("User");
    // Loading products in Background Thread
    String email = user.get_email();
    nothingfound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nothingFoundMSG);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.request_progress);
    new AsyncGetRequests().execute(email);
    RequestAdapter adapter = new RequestAdapter(this,arrayOfRequests);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.RequestList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //nothingfound.setText(Integer.toString(listView.getCount()));
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        /*mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        mForgotCreate.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mForgotCreate.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mForgotCreate.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });*/
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
       // mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        //mForgotCreate.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
private class AsyncGetRequests extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(Active_Requests.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{

            WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            //String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
            //System.out.print(ip);
            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("https://people.eecs.ku.edu/~cduddy/JunkAway/PullActiveRequests3.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Append parameters to URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", params[0]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Open connection for sending data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();//broken
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return(result.toString());

            }else{

                return("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        //System.out.println(result.toString());
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        showProgress(false);
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){

            // If username and password does not match display a error message
            Toast.makeText(Active_Requests.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new 
Intent(Active_Requests.this,NormalUser_HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Active_Requests.this.finish();

        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

            Toast.makeText(Active_Requests.this, "Oops! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new 
Intent(Active_Requests.this,NormalUser_HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Active_Requests.this.finish();
        }else
        {
            /* Here launching another activity when login successful. If you persist login state
            use sharedPreferences of Android. and logout button to clear sharedPreferences.
             */

            Toast.makeText(Active_Requests.this, "Got Requests", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String[] requests = result.split("!");
            String[] split;
            String[][] requestssplit = new String[requests.length][11];
            if(requests.length>0) {
                for(int i=0;i<requests.length;i++)
                {
                    requestssplit[i]=requests[i].split(":");
                    Request newREQ= new Request(requestssplit[i][0],requestssplit[i][1],requestssplit[i][2],requestssplit[i][3],requestssplit[i][4],requestssplit[i][5],requestssplit[i][6],requestssplit[i][7],requestssplit[i][8],requestssplit[i][9],requestssplit[i][10]);
                    arrayOfRequests.add(newREQ);
                    Log.d("Request Created:",newREQ.getDescription());
                    Log.d("Array Length:",arrayOfRequests.toString());
                }
            }
            //String test=Integer.toString(requests.length);
            //Request newREQ= new Request("80","cd.g","12885","Lawrence","Today","4","DO ITT","50","true","false","Open");
            //adapter.add(newREQ);
            nothingfound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            nothingfound.setText(result);

        }
    }

}
    }
```

XML for individual request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">
<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ReqID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:text="Request Number:"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:text="Date Requested:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:text="Short Description:"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<!-- The TextView's below this point - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PickupAdd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DropOffAdd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ItemCount"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Cost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DriverAccepted"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/User"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IsCompleted"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

XML for Main activity with listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nothingFoundMSG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="18sp"
    android:text="No Active Requests Found"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/request_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/RequestList"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` after you're done adding all the items to `arrayOfRequests`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. All of the results are in the array before the adapter is set for the listview.

Comment: No, they aren't. You're setting the `Adapter` in `onCreate()`, but you're starting an _asynchronous_ operation to fetch the items right before that. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` after the add loop in the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you! I had it there, but the app kept crashing, and stupid me never checked the log cat to see that I was trying to set a TextView with an integer value! Works now!!! If you want to put your comment as an answer below I'll mark it to give you the points!

Comment: It's cool. You can give it to deejay, if you like. Thanks, though. Appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding all the data in the listview Object but you are not notifying the data set changed to the adapter. You need to add this line at the end of the code where you are done adding the data to object.

```
  _youAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick. All of the results are in the array before the adapter is set for the listview, so when the array is passed to the adapter class, it's already populated.

Comment: you are adding the data to the array but the adapter is not updating the listview with array data. you need to add this `  _youAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` line of code after your for loop.

Comment: Thank you! I had it there, but the app kept crashing, and stupid me never checked the log cat to see that I was trying to set a TextView with an integer value! Works now!!!

Comment: ahan.. glad it worked. but for future reference, you can set the integer value to TextView by doing something like this. `tv.setText(_intergerValue + " ")` or `tv.setText(String.valueOf(_integerValue));`